# Getting Faster result on Ping in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, ping

I'm making a tool to test a connection to certain host using a class "PingReply" in .NET. My problem is it takes a while to get a result if the ping result is a fail. It is LAN environment so i can already assume that the connection is failed if it takes more than 100ms. The code below shows a result after 5 seconds, which is 5000ms, if the connection to the host fails. Can i get the faster result even though the connection is failed?

```
Ping x = new Ping();
PingReply reply = x.Send(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.1")); 
if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
{
    //Do something
}
```

Comment: You haven't provided your ping object.

Comment: did you try also with Ping class? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping.aspx

Comment: There is a timeout example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.pingreply.aspx)

Comment: Some of the behavior is going to follow the TCP/IP standard which allows for a timeout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a timeout to the Ping.Send() method. Please check out the overloaded members.

Comment: It should be noted that this method always uses a minimum of 500ms, even if you specify a timeout lower than that.

Answer (score 3):

[Ping.Send()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf697k33.aspx) has an overload with a timeout parameter:

```
PingReply reply = x.Send(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.1"), 100);
```

Answer (score 2):

Since we can't see your ping object, ill assume you don't know about TIMEOUT. I usually send an async ping, and set the timeout to 3 seconds.

```
 try
            {
                Ping ping = new Ping();
                ping.PingCompleted += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    if (e.Reply.Status != IPStatus.Success)
                        // Report fail
                    else                    
                       // Report success

                };
                ping.SendAsync(target, 3000, target); // Timeout is 3 seconds here
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return;
            }
```

Comment: Down votter: Please comment.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an async delegate to kick off the Ping. The async delegate has a function called BeginInvoke that will kick off a background thread that will immediately return a IAsyncResult. The IAsyncResult has a wait handler called AsyncWaitHandle which has a method called WaitOne which can be assigned a time to wait. This will freeze the current thread a given time in milliseconds, in your case 100, then you can use the property IsCompleted to check to see if the thread has completed its work. For Example:

```
Func<PingReply>  pingDelegate = () => new Ping().Send(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.1"));

IAsyncResult result = pingDelegate.BeginInvoke(r => pingDelegate.EndInvoke(r), null);

//wait for thread to complete
result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(100);

if (result.IsCompleted)
{
    //Ping Succeeded do something
    PingReply reply = (PingReply) result;

    //Do something with successful reply
}
```

Comment: Down votter: Please comment

Comment: They don't comment for some reason, i was down voted too...Your post seems well explained and detailed to me. +1 for you.

Answer (score 2):

I created a live host scanner too. It uses ARP to check if a computer is online.
An ARP request is much faster than if you'd ping a host.
Here's the code I used to check if a Host is available:

```
//You'll need this pinvoke signature as it is not part of the .Net framework
[DllImport("iphlpapi.dll", ExactSpelling = true)]
public static extern int SendARP(int DestIP, int SrcIP, 
                                 byte[] pMacAddr, ref uint PhyAddrLen);

//These vars are needed, if the the request was a success 
//the MAC address of the host is returned in macAddr
private byte[] macAddr = new byte[6];
private uint macAddrLen;

//Here you can put the IP that should be checked
private IPAddress Destination = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");

//Send Request and check if the host is there
if (SendARP((int)Destination.Address, 0, macAddr, ref macAddrLen) == 0)
{
    //SUCCESS! Igor it's alive!
}
```

If you're interested [Nmap also uses this technique](http://nmap.org/book/man-host-discovery.html) to scan for available hosts.

> ARP scan puts Nmap and its optimized algorithms in charge of ARP requests. And if it gets a response back, Nmap doesn't even need to worry about the IP-based ping packets since it already knows the host is up. This makes ARP scan much faster and more reliable than IP-based scans. So it is done by default when scanning ethernet hosts that Nmap detects are on a local ethernet network. Even if different ping types (such as -PE or -PS) are specified, Nmap uses ARP instead for any of the targets which are on the same LAN.

This only works within the current subnet! As long as there is no router between the requesting machine and the target it should work fine.

> ARP is a non-routable protocol, and can therefore only be used between systems on the same Ethernet network. [...]
> arp-scan can be used to discover IP hosts on the local network. It can discover all hosts, including those that block all IP traffic such as firewalls and systems with ingress filters.  - [Excerpt from NTA-Monitor wiki](http://www.nta-monitor.com/wiki/index.php/Arp-scan_User_Guide)

For more information on the SendARP function you can check the [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/iphlpapi/SendARP.html) documentation.