# Limit time for ping in C#

Tags: c#, timeout, ping

I need to ping ~20 computers in local network in short period of time. But if i use `Ping` class for non-existant host (computer is turned off) i have to wait ~2.5 seconds despite of 50 milliseconds timeout. How can i wait for PingReply only for 50 milliseconds and if no reply - simply check next host?

Here is code example:

```
foreach (var singleUser in userList)
{
    try
    {
        Ping userPing = new Ping();                    
        PingReply reply = userPing.Send(singleUser, 50);
        if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
        {
            userInfo.Add(singleUser, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        //host not exists
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe this s helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29094041/c-sharp-ping-delay-slow-under-mono

Comment: Thanks, i've read it. But i don't want to use async - code become more complex and there will be problem with handling HostNotFound exception for acync calls.

Comment: Disagree. Async is the only way to go on this one. System.Threading.Tasks make handling async operations very easy. Much easier than trying to find a synchronous solution to your problem.

Comment: You can't have you cake and eat it too.   Using a Synchronous method and shortening the time out will give false errors (not finding host).  So the correct solution is to use Asynchronous method.  To handle HostNotFound create a Dictionary of IP and Ping Response which is set to false.  Set response to True for every successful ping.  The responses that are left false are the HostNotFound.

Comment: @ShannonHolsinger I need to target on .Net 3.5, so I can't use System.Threading.Tasks.  @jdweng do you mean `Ping.SendAsync` or IAsyncResult like http://stackoverflow.com/a/14362045/2179676? And what about IP - if i use Dns.GetHostEntry("Myhost") - i also get HostNotFound exception after 2.5 seconds for disabled hosts.